# Complex root notation

Tags: notation, complex-numbers

Is there a standardized way to distinguish between real and complex roots? In other words, is there a convention about how to I formally write that I expect $\sqrt[3]1$ to be solved in $\mathbb C$, and not in $\mathbb R$?

I understand that a way to stress that I'm looking for real roots is to write $\sqrt[3]{|1|}$, but is there a standard notation to stress that I'm looking for complex roots?

---

**EDIT.** I'm sorry for not being clear enough. I understand that I can emphasize the fact we're talking about $\mathbb C$ (it's usually obvious from the context anyway), besides it never hurts to stress the *complex* root in the text itself.

I'm asking if there's a *special* symbol or a modification of $\sqrt{\cdots}$ which would be suitable for stressing out the complex root.

Maybe it's better to take this as a historical question about notation. Were there ever attempts to introduce something like, for example $\sqrt[\Large\text{[c]}]{\cdots}$ or $\sqrt{\cdots}^{\text{[c]}}$ or whatever?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that whenever $x$ is real, $\sqrt[3]x$ is always understood to mean the so-called "principal" cube root of $x$; that is the unique real cube root.  If I wanted to emphasize that you wanted a complex cube root I would use exponential notation, because that would let me express that I didn't care which cube root I was using (by including a factor of $e^{2ik\pi/3}$) or, if I did care, which one I wanted (by specifying $k$).

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I agree with you. I have edited my question to include additional information about what I'm interested in.